# Can you explain impacts of setting 'position' property on 'left' & 'top' properties?

Tags: html, css, position

if I have a div using a css class below:

```
{
  top: 100px;
  left:500px;
}
```

How does the coordinates specified above are influenced -how the visible position of the div would be shifted- in case of implementing each line below separately? (for example: is it also meaningless to set left & top properties in case a position is set to a specific value?)

```
position: absolute;
position: static;
position: fixed;
position: inherit;
position: relative;
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/KzWCW/ ...just play around with it to see how the different `position`-arguments work out in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
position: absolute;
```

The coordinates are the offset from any ancestor element with `position` with a value that is not `static`. If none exists, it is from the document.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/AQ734/).

```
position: static;
```

This is the default `position`. The offsets will not affect the position of the element.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/XQxBA/).

```
position: fixed;
```

The offset is relevant to the current scrolled portion of the viewport. Older IEs did not support this property.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Se9cN/).

```
position: inherit;
```

This will inherit from a parent element's CSS, if supported. Older IEs did not support this property.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/WzXrR/).

```
position: relative;
```

This will be relative to the element's normal position.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/TwFQY/).

Comment: Could you elaborate position: absolute a little bit more. If you talk on my example values, where should I expect the div relative to its container? +Is there any case that makes setting left and top properties meaningless?

Comment: @pencilCake: I will update my answer. With the default `position: static`, the `top` and `left` properties are meaningless.